# Make two values equal

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

I have two integers x and y. If the value is divisible by two, then I can remove a half of the value. If the value is divisible by three, then I can remove exactly two-thirds, and if the value is divisible by five, then I can remove four-fifths.

Now i want to make the values equal as quickly as possible. Find the minimum number of operations needed to make them equal.Or tell if it cant be done at all

Example : if x=15 and y=20 3 moves are required to make them equal

Answer (score 0):

Find $c = \gcd(x, y)$, then factor $x/c$, $y/c$ and pray that neither has a prime other than $2, 3, 5$. The factors will represent the moves that need to be made.

Example, $x=15$, $y=20$, $c=5$, $x/c = 3$, $y/c = 2\cdot 2$, so the moves are: divide $x$ by $3$, divide $y$ by $2$ and $2$.

Comment: What you mean by "pray that neither has a prime other than 2,3,5"?

Comment: @user3001932, try making $7$ and $8$ equal.

Comment: u mean if x/c and y/c factors are other than 2,3,5 its not possible to make them same.?